# YUI Compressor 2.4.7 - No class def error ErrorReporter

Tags: java, yui, minify, rhino, yui-compressor

I have a problem with the YUI Compressor for js: I've added version 2.4.7 to my build path in Eclipse ( tried with rhino jar and also without) - no effect whatsoever. I dont get compile errors, I can see the class I've created that implements org.mozilla.javascript.ErrorReporter, but when I try to run the compressor, I get:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mozilla.javascript.ErrorReporter from BaseClassLoader@1d81fd2

Comment: How do you run the compressor?

Comment: I'm using it like this: JavaScriptCompressor compressor = new JavaScriptCompressor(br,new SystemOutErrorReport() );
compressor.compress(output, 1 << 20, false, false, false, false);

Comment: So you run it in eclipse project?

Comment: yes, this is what I am trying. I want to minify scripts on the fly, at runtime

Comment: The yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar I built contains org.mozilla.javascript.ErrorReporter class. So it you can use JavaScriptCompressor, you can use ErrorReporter too. Could you please check yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar?

Comment: yes, it is there. and yet i still get the error

Comment: tried also with 2.4.7. Same problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26105/discussion-between-lhuang-and-iulia-muntianu)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I'm going to add an answer in case anyone else comes across this in a search.

I had the exact same problem.  The issue was that yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar wan't in our shared maven repository and so wasn't getting downloaded by the yuicompressor maven plugin.  To verify this check your local maven repository for the yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar (usually C:\Users\.m2\repository\com\yahoo\platform\yui\yuicompressor\2.4.7).  If it's there then you have a different issue if it's not then this could well be your issue.  To fix just upload yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar to your shared repository.